# Is there a simple way, in JavaScript, to get a String that a url points to?

Tags: javascript, html, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have a google sheet with a string in a cell. I found a way to generate a url that point to the string in that cell. For example, the following link goes to the String:

```
this is a test string from GSheet
```

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LGZNL5B4SL-lvkjuj2OxMSPdB66j5rEdx1b-ids7a0I/gviz/tq?tqx=out:html&tq=select%20A%20where%20A%20%21%3d%27%20%27

I'd like to get this string, given a url, from a js file.

...or I might be over complicating things and there's an easier way to get a string from Google Sheets?

My end goal is to have anybody with a link be able to update a string that is in a js file.

Answer (score 0):

There are these cute things called `query string parameters`. You can use them to retrieve non-private data from a URL.

To retrieve parameters that are visible in the url(We call these GET parameters) via javascript, you can check this answer:
[How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)